# Web service doesn't work exactly

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, mysqli

Well, I explain you what I'm trying to do, I need to insert an user from my android device to the localhost, I'm using a web service in php and it seems that it doesn't work because it says that I have inserted that user in my database but when I go to the localhost I don't find my user..

Here's my code:

Java(Android):

```
public class NewUsuarioPart2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText textoEmail, textoDNI, textoEdad,textoNombreUsu;
private Button btnHecho;
private String nom = "";
private String apellido = "";
private String contra = "";
private String contraNew = "";
private int id = 1;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuario_nuevo_part2);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        String str = "*** My thread is now configured to allow connection";

        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //LO GUARDADO DE NEWUSUARIOACTIVITY
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            nom = null;
            apellido = null;
            contra = null;
            contraNew = null;
        } else {
            nom = extras.getString("STRING_NOM");
            apellido = extras.getString("STRING_APELLIDO");
            contra = extras.getString("STRING_CONTRA");
            contraNew = extras.getString("STRING_CONTRA_NEW");
        }
    } else {
        nom = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_NOM");
        apellido = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_APELLIDO");
        contra = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_CONTRA");
        contraNew = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_CONTRA_NEW");
    }

    textoEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edEmail);
    textoDNI = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edDNI);
    textoEdad = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edEdad);
    textoNombreUsu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edNomUsu);

    btnHecho = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHecho);
    btnHecho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            id++;
            new Insertar(NewUsuarioPart2Activity.this).execute();
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewUsuarioPart2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

//What I do here is insert my new user to my database



 private boolean insertar(){

        HttpClient httpclient;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        HttpPost httppost;
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.231.88/xabiagame/data/insertarOtroMetodo.php"); // Url del Servidor
        //Añadimos nuestros datos
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(8);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",String.valueOf(id).trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre",nom.trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apellidos",apellido.trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",textoEmail.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dni",textoDNI.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contrasenya",contraNew.trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario",textoNombreUsu.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("edad",textoEdad.getText().toString().trim()));

        for (int i=0; i<nameValuePairs.size(); i++){
            Log.i("User", nameValuePairs.get(i).toString());
        }

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            return true;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //AsyncTask para insertar Personas
    class Insertar extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        private Activity context;

        Insertar(Activity context){
            this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(insertar())
                context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Persona insertada con exito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        nom = null;
                        apellido = null;
                        contra = null;
                        contraNew = null;

                        textoEmail.setText("");
                        textoDNI.setText("");
                        textoEdad.setText("");
                        textoNombreUsu.setText("");
                    }
                });
            else
                context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No insertado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my web service in Php (I have two):

And those two it seems that it doesn't work.

First one:

```
<?PHP
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";  //nuestro servidor
$database_localhost ="xabiagame";//Nombre de nuestra base de datos
$username_localhost ="root";//Nombre de usuario de nuestra base de datos (yo utilizo el valor por defecto)
$password_localhost ="";//Contraseña de nuestra base de datos (yo utilizo por defecto)

//'ejemplo.com:3307',  'usuario_mysql', 'contraseña_mysql'

$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)//Conexión a nuestro servidor mysql
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); //mensaaje de error si no se puede conectar
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);//seleccion de la base de datos con la qu se desea trabajar

//variables que almacenan los valores que enviamos por nuestra app, (observar que se llaman igual en nuestra app y aqui)
$id=$_POST['id'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$dni=$_POST['dni'];
$contrasenya=$_POST['contraseña'];
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$edad=$_POST['edad'];

$query_search = "insert into usuario(id,nombre,apellidos,email, dni, contraseña, usuario, edad) values ('".$id."','".$nombre."','".$apellidos."','".$email."','".$dni."','".$contrasenya."','".$usuario."','".$edad."')";//Sentencia sql a realizar
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());//Ejecuta la sentencia sql.

/* Consignar la transación */
if (!mysqli_commit($localhost)) {
    print("Falló la consignación de la transacción\n");
    exit();
}
/* Cerrar la conexión */
mysqli_close($localhost);

?>
```

The other one:

```
<?php

$id=$_POST['id'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$dni=$_POST['dni'];
$contrasenya=$_POST['contraseña'];
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$edad=$_POST['edad'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "xabiagame";
 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (id,nombre,apellidos,email, dni, contraseña, usuario, edad)
VALUES ('$id','$nombre','$apellidos','$email','$dni','$contrasenya','$usuario','$edad')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "se creo el usuario";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I don't know what's my error.. It seems that is all fine, i think..

Comment: your code is wide open to **SQL-Injection** attacks. just imagine someone POSTing a $edad like `'); DROP TABLE usuario; -- ` - please use parameterized statements to secure your system.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann this is a final project for my high school, I don't really care right know some attacks.. I know you're saying it properly and thank you for the advisement, but, right know I'm just trying to insert or to get info.. when I have already done that I will focus on parameterized statements... Thank you for your answe :D

Comment: well i couldn't have known that. anyway: that being a school project is **no** excuse for writing insecure code, since that way, you train yourself to write insecure code in the future. also: your code will break anytime when someone inserts any value containing a `'`.

Comment: Yeah, i know, i will put some methods to secure that, no problem.. like I said before, I preffer to get info or insert and then I secure that... I have done some projects before, but not in android and i had secured with prepared statements or some methods and that... thank you for your answer :D

Comment: are you sure that you are getting data from mobile to your php script? try printing some values out to cross check that your values are transferred from mobile to script.for now ignore inserting into DB

Comment: @RushiAyyappa well,i dind't tryed to do that. How can i Know if my php script works or receives data? I'm noob in php.. I only know that I receive data from my edit text and nameValuePairs it works because it saves the data..

Comment: This sort of thing get's asked a dozne times a day. Pleae test your php code with a simple HTML form before trying to connect to android.

Comment: @e4c5 well, I searched and I didn't found anything what I'm looking for..

Comment: there's nothing you can find by searching. What you need to do is to test your PHP independently as have already mentioned and your android code independently. When they working on their, then only you should consider putting them together

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you always assign the same `id` to the record you are trying to save in the database. Hence the error that the user already exists.

Check your code here:

```
private int id = 1;
```

This variable is never changed in your code, so all the records you are trying to save have `id=1`. In my opinion you should not send the `id` from your android application, its your database's job to assign the id to each new insert is made. Check for primary key strategies e.g. autoincrement.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but it isn't that i think, because when i put id equals 2 it shows me the same... user inserted but no one in my database

Comment: In your database, is the field `id` marked as Primary Key? If it is then for sure keeping the same `id` and inserting records will cause you problems. So this is one sure error. Now, try to debug your insert query by adding `echo $sql;` in your `php` just below the `$sql = "INSERT...` statement and try to run it in your database.

Comment: Yes, _id_ is marked as a Primary Key... When I run that php web service in [link]http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ it shows me: `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in [...][...]:17
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>17</b><br />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  $key= $input->value; //try like this for all below.
  /* $id=$_POST['id'];
 $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
 $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
  $dni=$_POST['dni'];
 $contrasenya=$_POST['contraseña'];
 $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
 $edad=$_POST['edad'];
 */
 $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "xabiagame";
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (id,nombre,apellidos,email, dni, contraseña,   usuario, edad)
  VALUES    ('$id','$nombre','$apellidos','$email','$dni','$contrasenya','$usuario','$edad')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "se creo el usuario";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Why you commented id, nombre, apellidos... etc ?

Comment: you try to get values this way .$key= $input->value..ex: $id=$input->id; do this way for all

Comment: I did in that way, and it tells me the same, user inserted but in my database nothing...